# canvas toDataUrl() not working on android devices workarund

Tags: android, canvas, todataurl

I'm developing Cordova hybrid Web application that uses Pixi (2d rendering library). Application creates some canvas that needs to be converted and saved on the server as PNG image.

**EDIT** (code):

```
var canvasImg = $('#canvas')[0].toDataURL("image/png");
$("#canvas-img").attr("src", canvasImg );
```

( this is just example of code I'm using to test *toDataURL()* )

*toDataURL()* is working fine in Web application running PC browser. It converts image correctly and shows the image in #canvas-img.

But, when I run Cordova App (on Android) or open it using Chrome Browser (on Android), then *toDataURL()* creates empty pixels dummy image.

I read about problems with toDataURL() in Android version < 2.3, but my android is version 6.0 !!

- Is my problem related with this *toDataURL()* issues on Android devices or something else?

Is there a workaround for *toDataURL()* not working on Android devices?

I tried to use:

- https://github.com/AdamMerrifield/todataurl-png-js
- https://github.com/hongru/canvas2image
- https://github.com/gillyb/reimg

(maybe I mess something but that didn't worked)

If someone find a workaround this problem please be kind to help!

Regards,
Josip

Comment: It wont help you so much, but I'm quite sure that this has to do with your implementation. This function works in your context ; I've used it before.

Comment: Then how can be that it works perfectly using the same web application on PC, and it doesn't by using Cordova iframe app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! Success =)

---

There wasn't a problem in *toDataURL()*, unless your Android version is < 2.3.

But, for backward compatibility, I've implemented **todataurl-png-js** (just in case).

---

### Workaround

My Pixi renderer was **PIXI.autoDetectRenderer** and it used WebGL renderer.
That's why *toDataURL()* always results in empty transparent dummy image.

- I changed renderer to **PIXI.CanvasRenderer** and now it converts canvas to image without problem!

*I hope this will help someone with the same problems!*

:: CHEERS ::

Josip